# Mod_rewrite: all traffic to goto https://www.<domain>.co.uk

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have currently got a site that will redirect all traffic to www.site.co.uk

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will currently send requests to:

```
site.co.uk
site.com
www.site.com
```

to

```
www.site.co.uk
```

which is fine, now however i want the site to be accessed via SSL so need it to do the follwing:

send requests from:

```
http://site.co.uk
http:// site.com
http://www.site.com
https://site.co.uk
https://site.com
https://www.site.com
```

to

```
https://www.site.co.uk
```

I have googled it and managed to get it part working but not fully but i dont really understand it, I dont have enough knowlage of this to make the changes for myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.co.uk/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

This will always redirect all those listed site's traffic to `https://www.site.co.uk`

Comment: Hi thanks! this works for all traffic accessing the site from  http: but if i goto h t t p s://site.com it doesnt redirect to : h t t p s ://www.site.co.uk

Comment: Actually it should redirect `site.com` as long as `site.com`'s DOCUMENT_ROOT is also pointing to the same directory. Can you try in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Did you try a new browser?